# Why doesn't type narrowing with double negation work in typescript?

Tags: typescript

If there is a double negative condition such as below, typescript is not able to resolve the type. In here, it will have a compile error on the variable `c`.

```
const testFunction = (a: number | null, b: number | null) => {
    if (!a && !b) {
        return;
    }
    const c: number = a || b;
}
```

I know that we can actually rewrite this with if else and throw exception. I am just wondering why makes this difficult to implement in typescript, and is there no more elegant way to write this in a way that typescript will understand?

Comment: `double negative condition` where exactly in this code double negation?

Comment: You are asking two questions here, which one is more important?  The reason why this is difficult is given in [microsoft/TypeScript#30869](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30869), whereas the "more elegant" way would be to perform the logic once instead of twice like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wER0ON).  On which question should an answer focus?

Comment: Probably the more elegant solution especially if the difficult part is already explained

Comment: I assume you meant to do -> `if (!a || !b)` ,  because if either is null, then it's not a number..

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript's [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) only works on individual variables or properties of variables, and it works on them independently.  So with a check like `if (!a && !b) { /* true */ } else { /* false */ }` the compiler will understand that `a` must be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and that `b` must be falsy inside the true block, but there is no corresponding independent narrowing that can be done to `a` and `b` inside the false block.  So `a` and `b` both stay their full `number | null` types there.

In order for your code as written to be verified as safe, the compiler would need to keep track of the state of not just each *variable*, but each *expression* (like `a || b`) or each *set of variables* (like `[a, b]`).  This isn't a big deal for two variables, but for the general case this is essentially impossible.  The number of sets of variables grows exponentially with the number of variables, and there wouldn't be enough time or memory for the compiler to accurately keep track of the full state in even a modestly sized function.

There was a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#30869](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30869) asking for the ability to track such things, but it was closed as "too complex".

---

That leaves us with refactoring.  If you care about `!a && !b` or its logical sibling `a || b`, you should copy the relevant value to its own variable `c` first, and then check *that* for truthiness.  This reduces the task of tracking some combination of `a` and `b` to the task of tracking just `c`, which the compiler is much better at doing:

```
const testFunction = (a: number | null, b: number | null) => {
    const c = a || b; // c is known as number | null here
    if (!c) return;
    c.toFixed(2) // okay, c is known to be number here
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.8.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BiBXMwoEtwwLwwAoBDALhjBQFsAjeAJxgB9yUAbVgGhmrIpvqYt2ASjwA+GAG8AsACgYCmKEixgeGESbNqAbjmKYmAGaEAhMFF14UFHTB75i4ADooIJJgAe8ACYEATKIA9EEwIADWRACecgC+QA)

Comment: Am I missing something?, if the OP uses the correct boolean logic, TS is happy anyway-> eg.  `if (!a || !b) {`   currently the OP is saying if both  `a` and `b`  are null short circuit return, but of course that means either  `a` or `b` possibly been null, and the reason for the error.

Comment: You are doing a different operation from the one the OP is doing. I’m not sure why you say yours is “correct”.  The OP wants to "fall back" to `b` if `a` is falsy, and only exit if `b` is also falsy.  Your version exits if either `a` or `b` is falsy.

Comment: Like I said, am I missing something.  `4 || null` and `null || 4` . NIow makes sense..